# ColdFusion debugging output in my Ajax

Tags: coldfusion

If I turn off "Enable Request Debugging Output", the 3rd option under the Debug Output Settings, then I no longer get debug info in my `$.ajax` call to a cfc with `access="remote"`.

That's good, but I'd like to keep it turned on for all my other programs and turn it off programatically for this one exception.  I put

```
<cfsetting showdebugoutput="false">
```

at the top of my Index.cfm, but that didn't turn off the debug output coming from the cfc.

Oh wait.  Never mind. 
I had to put the  in the function rather than in Index.cfm.

Comment: Is there a question here?  I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `_cf_nodebug=true` in ajax calls to remote methods.