# Keep ColdFusion debugging info from returning to jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

When making an Ajax call my return result successfully returns the expected value plus all of the html from the debugger. Is there a way to not return the debugging info without turning debugging off? Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax/ajax_test.cfc?method=ajaxTest&returnformat=plain",
        data:"field1=17",
        success: function(response) {
        var r=response;
        alert(r);
        }
        });
```

Comment: `<cfsetting showDebugOutput="no"/>` - think that will work inside the method

Comment: This looks similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561010/coldfusion-debugging-output-in-my-ajax).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<cfsetting showdebugoutput="false">
```