# ColdFusion request debugging output for CFC methods

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfc

I would like to use the ColdFusion Request Debugging Output from the context of my CFC web service.  Is this possible? Here is a sample CFC that I've tried to access:

/cfjunk/jsonBug.cfc:

```
<cfcomponent output="true">

<cffunction name="test" returntype="string" access="remote" returnformat="json" output="true">
    <cfset local.str = structNew()>
    <cfsetting showDebugOutput= "true">
    <cfscript>
    str = {a = "hello", b = JavaCast("int", 23)};
    </cfscript>
    <cfreturn SerializeJSON(local.str)>
</cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Requested via http://localhost:8500/cfjunk/jsonBug.cfc?method=test with Request Debugging turned on, yielding no actual debugging output.  As you can see, I've tried to force the issue by specifying showDebuggingOutput="true", to no avail.

Comment: What browser are you using? Also, does the /cfjunk have an Application.cfc in it? If not, is there an Application.cfc in the root? Does it possibly have debugging forcibly off, and are you further not destroying the REQUEST scope within onRequest()?

Comment: Using Chrome, although I'd be surprised if that was a factor.  There is no Application.cfc in either cfjunk or the root folder.  Are you asking because you have gotten debugging output working in this context?  I saw your earlier answer, and it sounded reasonable.  Something change your mind?

Comment: Yes, I copied your code line-for-line and put it into a /services directory within my local working cfserver and not only am getting coldfusion debugging output to the screen--I can't seem to forcibly shut it off/suppress it, without disabling debugging in the CFAdmin--still looking...

Comment: Ok, I removed your line of <cfsetting showDebugOutput= "true"> and that disabled debugging on my view, which means that you have something post-processing, which is shutting debugging off before the result hits your browser--still looking...

Comment: Hm, I even changed JVMs and it is still outputting debugging to the screen--are you *certain* debugging is enabled in the CFAdmin? I realize that sounds silly but it appears that nothing should really prevent it (other than a rogue cfsetting showdebugoutput=false somewhere)--even this guy has the opposite problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561010/coldfusion-debugging-output-in-my-ajax

Comment: Yes, I'm sure debugging is enabled - I can go to a .cfm in that same folder (or elsewhere on my server) and see the normal output.  Very strange that it works fine for you - I'm using ColdFusion Server Developer 9,0,1,274733 on Mac OS X.  I wonder if there is a patch I'm missing or something.  Thanks for looking.

Comment: The plot thickens, I've run this test at home on a CF9 install and see your behavior, yet my tests on CF8 produce debug info...

Comment: Ah, found your culprit. Updating my answer appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of debugging output in ColdFusion, within the context of direct CFC calls is slightly different between versions.

The latest version, ColdFusion 9.0.1, **suppresses** this debug information from the browser output. Therefore, you'll need another mechanism to debug CFCs directly, either by tracing/tailing the log, encapsulating all the CFC calls within a CFM that you can successfully display debugging output on, or opt to use an external debugger to monitor the calls, ie. [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), [Chrome Developer Tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html) or [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/).

In ColdFusion 8 and earlier, as well as the un-hotfixed ColdFusion 9.0, this debug information is displayed in the browser output.

Source: [Change in CFCs with Debugging and ColdFusion 9](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/6/30/Changing-in-debugging-with-CFCs-in-ColdFusion-9)